# How can I parse a `syn::Signature` from a `syn::parse::ParseStream`?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-proc-macros

I am experimenting with Rust procedural macros.

I would like to be able to create a macro that would be used to generate JNI invocation boilerplate.  Something like

```
jni_method!{com.purplefrog.rust_callable.Widget, fn echo_str(&str)->String}
```

I have the following code so far ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd7376cad397064f1fd880b9a5626312)):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate syn; // 1.0.33

use syn::parse::{Parse, ParseStream};
use syn::Signature;

struct Arguments {
    name: proc_macro2::Ident,
    signature: Signature,
}

impl Parse for Arguments {
    fn parse(tokens: ParseStream) -> Result<Arguments, syn::Error> {
        let name: proc_macro2::Ident = tokens.parse()?;
        let comma: Token![,] = tokens.parse()?;
        let signature: Signature = //tokens.parse()?;
            syn::item::parsing::parse_signature(tokens)?;

        Ok(Arguments {
            name: name,
            signature,
        })
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `parse_signature` call is in error:

```
error[E0603]: module `item` is private
   --> src/lib.rs:17:18
    |
17  |             syn::item::parsing::parse_signature(tokens)?;
    |                  ^^^^ private module
    |
note: the module `item` is defined here
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.33/src/lib.rs:363:1
    |
363 | mod item;
    | ^^^^^^^^^
```

What is the proper way to parse a `Signature` from a `ParseStream`?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a `Signature`? Depending on what you are actually trying to parse, you should use one of the following:

- **`Fn*` trait signature** (ex. `FnMut(usize) -> bool`)

  Parse into `syn::TraitBound` (in order to catch lifetime bounds not present in a just a path), then you can get the inputs/output from the parenthesized arguments of the last segment of the trait bound's path.
- **Bare function, aka function pointer** (ex. `fn(usize) -> bool`)

  Parse into `syn::TypeBareFn`, then you can get the inputs/output directly.
- **Function definition, including a body** (ex. `fn foo(x: usize) -> bool { x > 5 }`)

  Parse into `syn::ItemFn`, which includes a signature.
- **Foreign function definition** (ex. `fn foo(x: usize) -> bool`)

  Parse into `Struct syn::ForeignItemFn`, which includes a signature. Note that this is meant for declarations in `extern` blocks, so chances are this is not actually what you are looking for.

Comment: TraitBound lacks a name for the function.  I eventually worked around my problem by parsing an Ident and a TypeBareFn, but that makes the syntax a little inelegant.  ItemFn includes a body, which would confuse the users of the macro.  ForeignItemFn might be a good option, although it includes argument names which is not technically necessary, but might help folks reading the code later.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? I am worried that you may be going about this the wrong way. Can you update your question to provide an example input to the macro and how it would be used?

Comment: I have added my idea for how the macro would be used.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found an example of how to work around this problem ( https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/blob/master/examples/lazy-static/lazy-static/src/lib.rs ).  You are supposed to create your own `struct` and `impl Parse` for it.  I was able to build my own syntax from `Parse`able elements.

```
struct MySignature {
    pub parameter_types: Vec<Type>,
}

impl Parse for MySignature {
    fn parse(tokens: ParseStream) -> Result<Self, syn::Error> {
        let mut parameter_types: Vec<Type> = Vec::new();

        let arg_types: ParseBuffer;
        parenthesized!(arg_types in tokens);

        while !arg_types.is_empty() {
            let arg_type: Type = arg_types.parse()?;
            parameter_types.push(arg_type);

            if !arg_types.is_empty() {
                let _comma: Token![,] = arg_types.parse()?;
            }
        }

        Ok(MySignature { parameter_types })
    }
}
```